# How to edit an existing layer using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, vector, editing, leaflet-draw

I am used to working

with OL3 and I wanted to try using leaflet and see if it is as powerful as OL. I loaded a map with some data from a GeoServer WFS layer using this [tutorial](https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/) from Georepublic.

```
var group = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var geojsonlayer;
function handleJson(data) {
    //      console.log(data);
    geojsonlayer=L.geoJson(data, {
        style: function (feature) {
            return {
                "weight": 2,
                "opacity": 0.65
            };
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, my_Layer) {
            my_Layer.bindPopup("ID : "+feature.properties.id+"<br />Name : "+feature.properties.name);
        }
    }).addTo(group);
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
}
```

I wanted to add some editing and found the Leaflet.draw plugin I loaded it, and so far I can add a feature to the database ( knowing how painful it will be with WFS-T I used an AJAX call to a php script instead ). Here is how I call the draw control :

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    //Here I call the php script that stores the created feature in the DB
});
```

The problem is when I want to edit the existing features using the Leaflet.draw plugin, so I thought of changing the `featureGroup` in `edit` to `group` like this :

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
            featureGroup: group
    }
});
```

but now I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
```

I have done some research and found that I need to enable editing of the layer with this : `layer.editing.enable();` **the problem is where to add it so that when I click on the edit icon in the Leaflet.draw control I can edit my layer.**

I kind of liked the Leaflet.draw plugin menu on the side, is it possible to solve my problem using this plugin or should I make my own editing menu?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Not yet but I'm making a custom control using that same plugin to avoid this problem

Comment: What approach are you thinking of implementing for building the control?

Comment: Making a similar menu in html just for the editing and deleting. Catching the click or whatever events you choose and add the layer.editing.enable()

Comment: I'll post it as an answer when I finally make it

Comment: That's cool. I try to figure out if there is something we are missing. It should be possible to implement using only the plugin.

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps a bit. I am working on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932125/how-to-allow-only-one-feature-polygon-to-be-edited-at-a-time-with-leaflet

Comment: And this is another example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddproxy/suL12z93/3/ It must be something basic we miss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @user1919 who pointed me to the solution proposed in Stackoverflow, I could edit the existing layer with the plugin Leaflet.draw without customizing it ( at least not it's code ).

The edits now are made on the `onEachFeature` function in the `L.geoJSON` call like this:

```
var selectedFeature = null;
function handleJson(data) {
    geojsonlayer=L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            group.addLayer(layer);
            layer.on('click', function(e){
                if(selectedFeature){
                    selectedFeature.editing.disable();
                    // and Here I'll add the code to store my edited polygon in the DB or whatever I want to do with it
                }
                selectedFeature = e.target;
                e.target.editing.enable();
            });
        }
    }).addTo(group);
}
```

and so there is no need to use the edits from the menu in Leaflet.draw control

Now to use the Leaflet.draw control I had to add to the `drawnItems`, which is the editable layer defined in Leaflet.draw control,  the feature which I selected. It looks like this :

```
drawnItems.addLayer(e.target);
```

and define drawnItems in the edit of the Leaflet.draw control like this :

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
});
```

Comment: great job. I made it also work for markers. But for lines and polygons I still get errors. Does it work for all your geometries?

Comment: I am working only with polygons and it works

Comment: According to here the plugin doesn't work properly with Multi Geometries (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/560) Can you please confirm if your polygon geometries are of type Multipolygon or Polygon? Thanks.

Comment: I've checked in my DB and in GeoServer, my geometries are Polygons

Answer (score 4):

If my understanding is correct, the root cause of the issue resides in the fact that the layers you want to make editable through [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin are nested within a Layer Group (e.g. if they are built through `L.geoJSon()` factory, which outputs a Feature Group).

But Leaflet.draw does not like nested groups in the `drawnItems` Feature Group, so you have to add only "non-group" layers.

In that case, you would just need to "flatten" your Layer Group (if any) and extract only single / non-group layers, so that you can now safely add them into `drawnItems`.

```js
var geoJsonGroup = L.geoJson(myGeoJSON);
addNonGroupLayers(geoJsonGroup, drawnItems);

// Would benefit from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4461
function addNonGroupLayers(sourceLayer, targetGroup) {
  if (sourceLayer instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
    sourceLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      addNonGroupLayers(layer, targetGroup);
    });
  } else {
    targetGroup.addLayer(sourceLayer);
  }
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suL12z93/4/

Note: as mentioned in the code, there is actually a thread at [Leaflet issue #4461](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4461) about adding such a functionality to core Leaflet. I am sure Leaflet maintainers would be more than happy to receive a Pull Request to implement it! :-)