# Edit a shapefile with Leaflet.pm

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, editing

I am new to Leaflet but so far so good. I managed to add the plugins I needed and they work. Except the shapefile editing.

I am using [leaflet.pm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.pm?activeTab=readme) to draw, snap, cut polygons (only polygons). I also use 
the [Leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) to upload a shapefile in my map and convert it as a GeoJson. All of this works. My shapefile uploads perfectly and I can see my polygons. However, the editing does not. I tried to follow [this post and comments associated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709940/editing-a-shapefile-uploaded-using-leaflet-shapefile) without success.

I also followed [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet/203773#203773) but I am clearly stucked. I turned this in every directions I could tink off.

I saw in leaflet.pm page the part about [editing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.pm?activeTab=readme#edit-mode) but I am not sure how to use it / adapt it to my uploaded file.

This is my code: https://codepen.io/mscfourn/pen/YRZebJ

Can someone put me in the right direction using the edit mode of leaflet.pm?

PS: I checked the similar questions, they concern the plugin leaflet.draw, so I apologize in advance if you consider this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`map.on('pm:edit', function (e) {`

should be `drawnItems.on('pm:edit', function (e) {`

`e` is not very helpful without a lot of work. It does not contain the ID of the shape being edited nor does it contain the selected vertex. You would have to compare the `e._layers` to an earlier copy to get meaningful data.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is ;  First you will need to activate the edit mode.

```
{ map.pm.toggleGlobalEditMode();}
```

Then do the following to get the next layer after editing

```
map.on('pm:create', e => {
   var type = e.shape,
    layer = e.layer;
    
  layer.on('pm:edit', e=>{
      console.log(e.layer)
  })

})
```