# Leaflet draw - Edit event after editing existing feature

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I was inspired by this post
[How to edit an existing layer using leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet) I can click on an item to make it editable. 
But this does not "activate" the drawControl to allow me to click save or cancel, so I have not found out how I can catch an "edited" event to store the updated feature to my db?

Is there a way I can toggle the edit function for the drawControl to utilize the save/cancel after I manually made a layer editable?

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e){
                if(selectedFeature)
                     selectedFeature.editing.disable();
                selectedFeature = e.target;
                e.target.editing.enable();
           });
```

As noted by TomazicM. `drawnItems.addLayer(e.target);` need to go inside the onEachFeature function.

To make the save/cancel option to show up I faked a button click on the edit button. `document.querySelector(".leaflet-draw-edit-edit").click();` To fake a click on cancel button `document.querySelector("ul li:last-child a").click();`

Comment: Code above is only a part of required code from the example you are referring to. What about the rest: `drawnItems.addLayer(e.target);` and `var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({ …`?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something basic I did wrong. Adding drawnItems.addLayer(e.target); inside the click event made it work.

Comment: To make the save/cancel option to show up I faked a button click on the edit button.
document.querySelector(".leaflet-draw-edit-edit").click();
To fake a click on cancel button
document.querySelector("ul li:last-child a").click();

Comment: Publish your complete solution as answer. It's easier to find if someone needs it and if it's marked as accepted.

Comment: Please publish you solution as answer to your own question, not as edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem can be found here:
[https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/129](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/129#issuecomment-466672085)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).